# Найти сумму целых положительных чисел, кратных 9 в диапазоне от 1 до 100

Tags: python, tkinter

Найти сумму целых положительных  чисел, кратных 9  в диапазоне от 1 до 100.

Answer (score 2):

***Пример:***

```py
print(sum(x for x in range(9, 100, 9)))
```

***stdout:***

```py
594
```

Comment: Можно и без цикла: (9+99)/2*11 